# Basic SQL Queries - retrieve set based on foreign key

Tags: sql, return, subset

So I'm new to SQL queries, and am practicing a few basic ones - unfortunately, I appear to be stuck on one and thought I would inquire about how to restrict my result.

First, the question:

```
List departments that have more than one position.
```

I have a Position table and a Dept Table.

Position Table Columns:

```
 posid (positions ID), DeptID (foreign key)
```

Dept Table Columns:

```
Dept_Id (key), Dept_name
```

I currently have the following query:

```
SELECT D.Dept_name, P.posid 
FROM DB.positions P INNER JOIN DB.dept D 
ON P.DeptID = D.Dept_Id 
ORDER BY D.Dept_name;
```

With the following return set:

```
    Dept_name   posid
1   HR          102
2   HR          105
3   IT          109
4   IT          101
5   IT          110
6   Receiving   103
7   Receiving   106
8   Sales       108
9   Sales       107
10  Sales       104
```

As you can see, there are two different positions for HR, 3 for IT, etc.

I *want* my return result to then list *just* the following:

```
HR
IT
Receiving
Sales
```

How can I return this set? I know I can use COUNT - but I don't know how to get that to work with this return set, or how to do a nested subquery (remember, am learning, just started this week...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT D.Dept_name
FROM DB.positions P INNER JOIN DB.dept D 
  ON P.DeptID = D.Dept_Id 
GROUP BY D.Dept_name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY D.Dept_name;
```

The `HAVING` clause will only return dept's that have more than 1 position.

Comment: But doesn't this just count the number of Dept_names? I'm specifically looking for number of positions.

So would this be HAVING COUNT(P.posid) > 1?

Comment: run it and you'll see that it only returns rows for depts that have more than 1 position.

Comment: Running it results in error:   Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group.

Comment: did you run something different than the one in my answer?

Comment: Wait - my mistake. I had an extra bit left in there. But what is happening here that I could not see before? I'm trying to learn why this works... I understand that you are selecting Department names from two joined tables based on the foreign key. You are grouping by the Dept name... When you say Having Count(*) > 1, why is the "*" counting Position, and not department? Or *is* it counting dept?

Comment: The `HAVING COUNT(*)` simply means how many rows are being grouped based on the `GROUP BY` criteria.  When you run the query without the `GROUP BY` you can see how many rows the count(*) represents.

Comment: Okay. Sounds like my misunderstanding or lack of knowledge falls in the GROUP BY category. I'll go read more on that. Your answer makes sense though - especially with that explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Read up on *Group By*

your query should look something like this

```
SELECT D.Dept_name
FROM DB.positions P INNER JOIN DB.dept D 
     ON P.DeptID = D.Dept_Id 
Group By D.Dept_name
Having count(P.posid ) > 1
Order By D.Dept_name;
```

which is the same as the other answer posted here